# Каковы математические основы работы алгоритма построения отрицательных чисел с помощью дополнительного кода?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, системы-счисления

Посмотрел немало роликов про способ представления отрицательных чисел в компьютере. Но у всех них объяснение вида: говорится о том, что алгоритм нужен, чтобы избежать ввода отдельной операции вычитания, даётся алгоритм построения отрицательных чисел с помощью дополнительного кода, магическим образом все работает - складывается.

Так вот, каковы математические основы работы данного способа?

Comment: Как насчёт почитать книжку вместо посмотреть ролики?

Answer (score 8):

Сравнение по модулю, взятие остатков от деления — вот и все основы.

Вам аналогию привести? Давайте рассматривать трехзначные числа, например. И рассматривать их просто по модулю — ну, как остаток при делении на 1000.

Как вы понимаете, при прибавлении 1000 к любому числу после взятия остатка оно остается тем же.

Тогда отрицательное число можно записать как положительное, просто прибавив 1000.

```
-200 == -200 + 1000 == 800
```

И вычитание работает как сложение

```
500 - 200 == 500 + (-200) == 500 + 800 == 1300 == 300
```

Вот и всё. Просто интересующее вас представление рассматривает остатки от деления на 2<sup>n</sup>, где n — количество бит в представлении.

Возьмите бумажку, распишите парочку примеров. Например, -1 в случае байта (8 бит):

```
-1 == 100000000 - 1 == 11111111 (тут запись в двоичной системе счисления)
```

Теперь стало понятнее?